# Unable to connect to NI roboRIO on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, usb, ethernet

I have an ARM controller that I am trying to connect to with either ethernet or USB-B, but I am unable to make a connection with either. I am not able to test any other wired connections. I am running Kubuntu 14.04

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:40:ff:6b

```
      inet6 addr: fe80::468a:5bff:fe40:ff6b/64 Scope:Link

      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

      Interrupt:19
```

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:40:ff:6b

```
      inet addr:169.254.9.20  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0

      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      Interrupt:19
```

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

```
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1

      RX packets:2440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:2440 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 

      RX bytes:231381 (231.3 KB)  TX bytes:231381 (231.3 KB)
```

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ca:05:2a:86:2c:f2

```
      inet6 addr: fe80::c805:2aff:fe86:2cf2/64 Scope:Link

      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

      RX bytes:327 (327.0 B)  TX bytes:2192 (2.1 KB)
```

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:27:1e:24:a7:51

```
      inet addr:10.97.50.23  Bcast:10.97.63.255  Mask:255.255.240.0

      inet6 addr: fe80::5627:1eff:fe24:a751/64 Scope:Link

      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:12437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:11374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

      RX bytes:6060338 (6.0 MB)  TX bytes:3155794 (3.1 MB)
```

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.10 as my main operating system and use it program the roboRIO. My team has actually never deployed code to the roboRIO from Windows this season. I have teammates who use Ubuntu 14.04 also. Double check to make sure that you have set up your IP address and everything else correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use windows to program the roboRIO according to NI's website quoted below:

"Can I use a Linux computer to program roboRIO?
You will still need to use a Windows computer to program and control the roboRIO as the roboRIO tool chain is only supported in Windows."

Found here:
https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-30419